# Multiple Nested IF statements in MS Excel - brackets not right?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

I am trying to write a statement that does the following:

If R7 = "Yes" AND S7 = "Yes" AND T7 = "Yes", then output 1

If R7 = "Yes" AND S7 = "Yes" AND T7 = "No", then output 2

If R7 = "Yes" AND S7 = "No" AND T7 = "Yes", then output 3

If R7 = "Yes" AND S7 = "No" AND T7 = "No", then output 4

IF anything else, then output 5

I have written the following statement:

```
=IF(R7="Yes",IF(S7="Yes",IF(T7="Yes",1),IF(R7="Yes",IF(S7="Yes",IF(T7="No",2),IF(R7="Yes",IF(S7="No",IF(T7="Yes",3),IF(R7="Yes",IF(S7="No",IF(T7="No",4)))))))),5)
```

I know I am close however, issue is when it should display 4, it just displays “FALSE” - have I got my brackets in the wrong order?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to nest so many `IF` statements, you can use the `AND` function.

```
=IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="Yes",T7="Yes"),1,IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="Yes",T7="No"),2,IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="No",T7="Yes"),3,IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="No",T7="No"),4,5))))
```

This should work for you.

For further reading, see the [office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9).

Comment: Hi there! Thanks so much for the quick response. Really appreciate it! I had to change a couple of the "yes" and "no" on your reply, but the structure was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Iturner ... hope you don't mind ... just updated your answer to have the correct yes/no combinations!

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 thanks - didn't realise I was making up my own combinations! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct your formula as follows ...

```
=IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="Yes",T7="Yes"),1,(IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="Yes",T7="No"),2,IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="No",T7="Yes"),3,IF(AND(R7="Yes",S7="No",T7="No"),4,5)))))
```

Note that this function returns `5` when there is no matching combination ...

---

[image]

Comment: thanks for that! Looks like yourself and lturner had the same response - great minds think alike :) Appreciate the assistane. This forum is simply awesome :)

Comment: Indeed. Good answers are often like buses!! :0) Glad I could help.

Comment: The courteous SO thing would be to accept @lturner's answer so the question doesn't stay in the Unanswered stack.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Or my answer :0p

Comment: Oops, I did mean your answer :(

Comment: Definitely not - just a bit p***ed. Really shouldn't answer ?'s when I am.

Comment: Totally off topic, but I'm going to have to join you for a drink ... it's been one of those days :0\

Comment: Thanks again to all. @Mark - I just figured out how to accept answer.  Am new to the site so just getting a feel for it still :-)